# Copying download link to curl does not work

Tags: linux, download, curl, opera

I'm downloading an ISO image with Opera browser on Linux:

[image: Opera download]

I get the download link by right click:

[image: Right click to get download link]

Then I want to use `curl` on Linux console, but I cannot:

```
curl -O https://software-download.microsoft.com/db/Win10_1903_V2_English_x64.iso?t=3bbd00d6-f352-44fe-8d54-39823648e16f&e=1570698933&h=9209eec4d6644bf387d305a0fcc20fd3
```

The `curl` command just returns almost immediately without any useful download. I wonder why this is happening?

Comment: Does Opera provide some Network tab in its Developer Tools, which may provide some "Copy as cURL" command? You're probably missing some cookies. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/replay-a-network-request-in-curl to see what I mean for Chrome. Please edit your title to summarize the question.

Comment: Depending on your console it will try to interpret the `&`. Check what happens if you wrap the link in quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your URL contains `?`, `=` and `&` which may be special characters for your shell. They will be interpreted and, for example, put the command into a  background job. Run `jobs` to see if there is a `curl` command still running.

Two solutions:

- Wrap the `https://…` URL in double quotes
- Escape the special characters with a `\`

So, both should work:

```
curl -O "https://software-download.microsoft.com/db/Win10_1903_V2_English_x64.iso?t=3bbd00d6-f352-44fe-8d54-39823648e16f&e=1570698933&h=9209eec4d6644bf387d305a0fcc20fd3"

curl -O https://software-download.microsoft.com/db/Win10_1903_V2_English_x64.iso\?t\=3bbd00d6-f352-44fe-8d54-39823648e16f\&e\=1570698933\&h\=9209eec4d6644bf387d305a0fcc20fd3
```